# What are the typographically correct ways to name chapters in a book in Spanish?

Tags: puntuación, números

I have recently been surprised by Spanish punctuation in a number of ways. Currently I am struggling with two problems I have conflated here: dashes and Roman vs Arabic numerals.

A book I am reading atm has this format of naming chapters:

**Capítulo I. Procedimiento de arbitraje**

My questions are the following:

1. Does Spanish punctuation allow the use a dash here? → **Capítulo I.  — Procedimiento de arbitraje** *(In French, English, Polish, Czech, Russian, Slovak, German and others you can, but Spanish seems to use dashes that way quite infrequently — or is it me?)*
2. Does Spanish punctuation allow the use of Arabic numerals in chapters? → **Capítulo 1. Procedimiento de arbitraje** *(i.e. in Polish or Czech you can go with both numbering styles)*

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.  If you publish with an established firm, they will have their house rules and you'll have to live with them; if you self-publish, you can do what you want (but I hope you'll be consistent with whatever scheme you come up with).  I don't understand why you say you're struggling.  The way the question is written, it's not clear how it's based on anything other than idle curiosity.

Comment: @aparente001 well, typography is what I am asking about. Which part is unclear? I bave read the rules, but they don't answer all questions that rules in other languages answer clearly. For instance, rules say it can only.be "Primer capítulo", but three books in a row have "Capítulo I.". Hence I am asking about both normative standards and common usage.

Comment: You said you were struggling.  How so?  What leads you to be interested in this?  Do you want to know what rules publishers give their authors?  Do you want to know what common practice is?  Is your interest confined to modern publishing, or is there a broader period that interests you?

Comment: @aparente001 I was about to answer your comment broadly, but tbh I don't really understand your question. Can you answer this: *“1. Does Spanish punctuation allow the use a dash here?”*? If you can, then please provide an answer. If there is a difference between official rules and common usage, please relate to this. If this changed over time, please relate to this. If this varies between Spanish-speaking countries, please relate to this. It seems as if you required me to know all potential problems in advance. In Czech it took me 15 minutes to learn all the punctuation by comparison.

Comment: @MrVocabulary - Thank you.  I think I'm starting to understand better what you said about struggling.  You are looking for a simple rule or set of rules, because you are interested in comparing among various languages.  Also, you are interested in how the rules might have changed over time.  Is that right?

Comment: Well, I want to reformat an ebook to a format I am more familiar with, and I am wondering if it conforms to official and unwritten rules in Spanish, namely the two cases I quoted.

Comment: Aha.  That would be worthwhile adding to the question.

Comment: @aparente001 tbh I disagree, as it should in no way change answers. Same standards exist regardless of my purposes. Same goes for question such like "how do you spell X".

Comment: It's your question. I won't be subversive and add that information to your question myself.  Your comment will probably not be erased, so in practice it doesn't really matter; but I've consistently seen on ELU, a more established language site, that it's considered good practice to explain motivation for word, phrase and expression requests.  In this case, you are essentially doing a print formatting request.  The more you can explain about why you want to know, the better volunteers can help you.

Comment: Is it fiction or nonfiction?  Typically how long are the chapter titles?  Will they wrap around?  Can you give us a screenshot of what you are proposing that it will look like?  (You can change the text to some dummy Lorem Ipsum text if you wish.)  How much would it bother *you* if your table of contents had a somewhat non-standard look to it?

Comment: @aparente001 I am talking primarily about fiction. As for the other details—that assumes I know the relevant categories in advance, which I don't. Also I don't treat this as a case-dependent category; I am looking for rather generalized approach :)

Comment: @MrVocabulary - That's what the Lorem Ipsum dummy text is designed for.  It really helps visualize page and webpage design and layout.

Answer (score 1):

The dash seems quite odd to me in both English and Spanish.  I would expect a single unit of punctuation between chapter and title, but generally a period or a colon.  A period *and* a dash seems excessive, if not outright incorrect.

You can use either ordinal or cardinal numbers either numeric or spelled out, but in modern times it's more common to see cardinals after the noun, and ordinals before it.

Comment: I see, thanks. But does “Capítulo 21” work? When googled, it mostly spills out TV series episodes.

Comment: @MrVocabulary - I checked some of the books on my shelf and none of them had "Capítulo 21."  However, some of them had "21."  (None had the dash.)

Comment: @aparente001 I see, thanks!

Comment: @MrVocabulary: there is nothing wrong with "Capítulo 21".  You could format it any of the following ways: *Capítulo 21*, *Capítulo 21.º*, *Capítulo veintiuno*, *Capítulo vigésimoprimero*, *Vigésimoprimer capítulo*, *21.ᵉʳ capítulo*, *Capítulo XXI*, *XXI Capítulo*, in addition to as aparente001 mentioned, just using the number by itself.

Comment: I've also seen no punctuation between the number and the text.